# Why don't I get a list of response.text objects using multiprocessing and my code freezes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'd like to save time and use multiprocessing to make 10 get-requests. So far I have this:

```
# get one text from the url
def get_one_request_text(url, multiprocessing_queue):
    response = requests.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    multiprocessing_queue.put(response.text)
```

```
# urls is a list of links
def get_many_request_texts(urls):
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    jobs = []
    result = []
    for url in urls:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_one_request_text, args=(url, q))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in jobs:
        p.join()
    for _ in jobs:
        result.append(q.get())
    return result
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # for testing purposes I use the same link
    url = 'https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000138'
    urls = [url] * 10 # any number freezes my code, even 1
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    texts = get_many_request_texts(urls)
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Soups: {len(texts)} Execution time: = {round(t2 - t1, 2)} {texts}")
```

I expect my script to produce 10 `response.text`'s in a list but for some reason my program just freezes and I don't get anything. Even when I try to get 1 response.text, it freezes.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get my response.texts using multiprocessing to save time?

Comment: It actually does not freeze but for some reason the `p.join()` call is excessively slow due to the size of the page fetched.  Put only the first 100 characters of the page in the queue (i.e., `multiprocessing_queue.put(response.text[0:100])`) and you'll see it terminates quickly.

Comment: @qouify I never would have thought it depends on the length of the response.text, thank you. I guess this is a non-effective way of parsing pages, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is probably a job better suited for multithreading rather than multiprocessing. Second, regardless of whether you are using multithreading or multiprocessing, this would be more easily accomplished if you used a thread or process pool.

That said, given you are doing what you are doing, the problem is that you must *never* attempt to read from the queue that your processes have written to after you have joined those processes. That is, those processes must still be running for your main process to retrieve those messages. So you need to reverse the order of operations:

```py
def get_many_request_texts(urls):
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    jobs = []
    result = []
    for url in urls:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_one_request_text, args=(url, q))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for _ in jobs:
        result.append(q.get())
    for p in jobs:
        p.join()
    return result
```

See [multiprocessing.Queue documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=queue#multiprocessing.Queue):

> **Warning** As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a queue (and it has not used `JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread`), then that process will not terminate until all buffered items have been flushed to the pipe.
>
> **This means that if you try joining that process you may get a deadlock unless you are sure that all items which have been put on the queue have been consumed.** Similarly, if the child process is non-daemonic then the parent process may hang on exit when it tries to join all its non-daemonic children.
>
> Note that a queue created using a manager does not have this issue. See [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=queue#multiprocessing-programming).